# parse authentication from ldap to apache without password

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, ldap, redhat

I am running apache on EC2 Redhat Linux.

Server version: Apache/2.2.15
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)

I have ldap attache to it. I would like to have uses not enter id or password when then type my application url in web browser.

Is there a way to do it?

Here is my httpd.conf

```
<location />
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthName "Web Console Authentication"
    AuthLDAPBindDN <user>
    AuthLDAPBindPassword <password>
    AuthLDAPURL <ldapusl>
    AuthUserFile /dev/null
    require valid-user
</location>
```

but this needs user to enter ID and password?

Please let me know if you need any information.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you require authentication ?

Comment: Do you need a user/password at all? If not, just remove all the Auth* stuff. Or do you want to implement single sign on so the current (windows) user is passed from the browser to the server?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to address that, yes user need to have ID and password. But when user click URL it should take windows authentication and pass it to application. So that user don't have to enter ID and password but he should have permission to access URL.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response to comments you're going to need to use [mod_ntlm](http://modntlm.sourceforge.net/) for that